# Initiallizing an Array of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I am initializing and array of objects, i need something like this:

```
Greyhound[1].StartingPosition = pictureBox1.Location;
Greyhound[2].StartingPosition = pictureBox2.Location;
```

and so on.. 
but I need to make it by a loop

```
for ( ......... ) 
      { Greyhound[i].StartingPosition = ????????? // what should go here }
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?  And what is "pictureBox2"?  A variable?  A field?  A property?

Comment: I assumed and tagged this C#. If this is incorrect, please retag

Comment: What happened to Greyhound[0]?

Answer (score 1):

If this is C# then something like this should work:

```
int max = 5;
for(int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
   Greyhound[i].StartingPosition =  this.Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i.ToString(), true)[0].Location;
}
```